# Defining lapidarical

Tags: meaning, seventeenth-century-english

In [this study](https://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/Tillyard01.html) of The Great Chain of Being, Diamonds among other various gems are classified as a **lapidarical primate**.

The [Oxford Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/) does not include lapidarical or even it's root word, lapid. Wikipedia and various online sources cite Lapid as an [Israeli community settlement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapid) but I don't think that is the appropriate definition here.

My English teacher suggested that it could perhaps be describing a property unique to the various gems described (Diamond, rubies, sapphires, topaz, chrysolite) however the question remains as to what.

What does **lapidarical** mean?

Comment: FYI, *lapid* means torch in Hebrew.

Comment: Look up "lapidary".

Comment: You’re only a stone’s throw away.

Comment: I would tentatively gloss it as "pertaining to lapidary" where *lapidary* is a book, or more abstractly a body, of pseudoscientific lore about gemstones. The point being made is less about stones themselves than about cultural beliefs and practices regarding them.

Comment: "primate" is probably used in the rare sense of "Chief place, primacy", which seems to be mainly used around 16th century (OED), so "lapidarical primate" means something that has a very important place in the (pseudoscientific) study of gems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does lapidarical mean?

A search of the OED for words beginning "lapidar..." gives

> 1. † lapidar, adj. First recorded ?1764
>    *...Of the nature of stone....*
> 2. lapidarian, adj. First recorded 1683
>    *...Executed in, or inscribed on, stone....*
> 3. † lapidarious, adj. First recorded 1656
>    *...Consisting of stones: stony....*
> 4. lapidarist, n. First recorded 1607
>    *...= lapidary1a2b; also figurative...*.
> 5. lapidary, adj. and n. First recorded a1382
>    *...Of an inscription, etc.: Engraved on stone, esp. monumental stones.Of style, etc.: Characteristic of or suitable for monumental
>    inscriptions....*

Given the length of time that words beginning "lapidar..." have been in the language, and given the absence from the OED of "**lapidarical**", I would say that it is not a recognised word.